# Using enums in an object-orientated way when they apply to many classes

Tags: java, oop, enums

So, I here was my previous code:

```
public enum eDay {
eMON,
eTUE,
eWED
}

eDay day = eMON;

switch( day ) {
case eMON:
//load class 1
break;

case eTUE:
//load class 2
break;

case eWED:
//load class 3
break;
}
```

Reading around, the OO way to do things is to have an enum that overrides a method rather than using a switch statement, such as:

```
enum eDay {
    eMON {
        @Override
        public void loadClass() {
            //load class 1
        }
    },
    eTUE {
        @Override
        public void loadClass() {
            //load class 2
        }
    };
    public abstract void loadClass();
}

void aMethodSomewhere(final eDay e) {
    e.loadClass();
}
```

While the concept of using polymorphism makes sense to me, rather than using a switch statement, what happens in the situation where the enum is used in different classes to do different things? For example, different classes behave differently according to a limited set of options, defined in the enum ( so not always performing loadClass() ).

Should you define different methods according to the different classes? To my mind, that would increase object coupling greatly.

I would really like to do OO properly, so good advice is much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: In Java classes should be named in `PascalCase`. I'm not sure what `eDay` is - does the `e` stand for `enum`? In which case that should already be obvious from the code.

Comment: I think this approach is correct from an OO perspective, you are using a Java construction (enum) to resolve the class you want to use by using an abstract method that resolves to the proper class, which is basically doing IoC for resolving dependencies. I wrote a micro-framework called Maker Factories that does something similar to do dependency injection and IoC from a Bean Context created upon Java enums. You may find it interesting: https://github.com/raspacorp/maker More documentation and examples still in progress.

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly give that some investigation; looks very interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you want to use polymorphism to avoid `if()` blocks and for behavior reuse, you should favor composition.

In your case, I understand that there is some dynamic behavior involved in your design and, therefore, the use of enums could not be advisable.

Enums have a lot of advantages: they're final, static and every instance is a singleton by default. Whenever I need a static singleton that is up when the JVM starts, I favor enums over classes.

In this case, if you have some dynamic behavior going on, you could write a class with some static final properties that are an instance of the same class. With proper visibility modifiers for constructors or factory methods, the external API of the class could be the same as with the enum.

In order to inject the dynamic behavior, you could use [Strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or even inject a Function (if you're using Java8) as a parameter in the class' constructor.

```
public static class eDays {
  public static final eDay eMON = new eDay(i -> i + 1);
  public static final eDay eTUE = new eDay(i -> i + 2);

  public static class eDay {
    private final Function<Integer, Integer> loadClassStrategy;

    public eDay(Function<Integer, Integer> loadClassStrategy) {
      this.loadClassStrategy = loadClassStrategy;
    }

    public int loadClass(int i) {
      return loadClassStrategy.apply(i);
    }
  }
}

void aMethodSomewhere(final eDays.eDay e) {
  e.loadClass(1);
}

// or even...

void aMethodSomewhere() {
  eDay eMON = new eDay(i -> i + 1);
  eMON.loadClass(1);
}
```

If your behavior is not dynamic, you could continue using enums, but you could inject the behavior in their constructor to improve readability:

```
public enum eDay {
  eMON(i->i+1),
  eTUE(i->i+2);

  private final Function<Integer, Integer> loadClassStrategy;

  eDay(Function<Integer, Integer> loadClassStrategy) {
    this.loadClassStrategy = loadClassStrategy;
  }

  public int loadClass(int i) {
    return loadClassStrategy.apply(i);
  }
}

void aMethodSomewhere(eDay e) {
  e.loadClass(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very comprehensive answer! Good point about enums being Singletons by default; I'll bear that in mind in future.

Answer (score 1):

**Enum** in Java is used for the non-changeable and defined constants.
It seems to me that you would like to have differently behaived classes based on some conditions. If so the strategy patter would be more suitable for this task.

For more info click [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-strategy).

Comment: Thank you. I think this seems like the most suitable answer: after having a quick look at the strategy pattern, it seems like I can implement different behaviour according to the calling class.

Comment: dependency Injection is an alternative.  
http://www.objc.io/issues/11-android/dependency-injection-in-java/

Comment: It's possible to implement the strategy pattern using an enum. One example is in [this thread](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37683/implementation-of-the-strategy-pattern).

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against putting this kind of behavior in enums; that's really not what they are designed for<sup>*</sup>. Instead, it might be better to maintain a map of enums and handlers.

```
Map<Eday, Loader> enumHandlerMap = new EnumMap<>();
```

`Loader` should be an interface (basically the stuff you had in your enum):

```
public interface Loader {
    void loadClass();
}
```

Then you can initialize your your handler map like so:

```
enumHanderMap.put(EDay.MON, new Loader() {
    @Override
    public void loadClass() {
        ...
    }
});
```

And you can run a handler like so:

```
enumHandler.get(eDayEnum).loadClass();
```

<sup>*</sup>To clarify, the semantic conveyed by enums is that you are dealing with a **static**, **predefined** set of values. I think an acceptable form of logic to include within enums is the kind that provides additional information about each of the values. The [`Planet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) enum is a good example because it provides additional information related to each enum. There is no strict rule to define what is "too much" logic. But if you find yourself implementing a method on an enum that talks to a database, or makes an HTTP connection, I would argue that you're doing too much. In general, the logic you implement inside the enum shouldn't concern itself with other parts of your model or business logic; it shouldn't need access to additional entities from your model, or other services. If you can convey additional information and behavior *in the context of the enum itself*, then you might be alright. But if you are using the enum to implement complex behavior that involves *other* entities or services, then the enum is doing too much.

Comment: "I'd advise against putting behavior in enums; that's really not what they are designed for." ... I can't agree.  The ability to associate behavior with enum groups or even to define constant-specific behaviors is a major advantage of Java rich enum types.  Protecting against "run away enums" should come from designing them carefully and in the context of an appropriate abstraction ... and not by slavishly following certain rules of the road.

Comment: Surely you meant to use [EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) instead of HashMap... right?

Comment: @scottb Of course, the right answer is "it depends" and I have definitely added behavior to enums before. But if your enum is doing stuff like loading classes, I'm not sure that you're using them correctly. What I was alluding to, as you mentioned, was "runaway enums".

Comment: @Powerlord `HashMap` works, but yes `EnumMap` would be better for performance. However if you have "extensible enums" that use a marker interface then it's difficult to use `EnumMap`.

Comment: @Powerlord:  For extensible enums based on an interface type, such as Vivin's, it is commonly infeasible (without using a generic intersection type) to use `EnumMap`.  Moreover, the performance benefits of EnumMap over HashMap are not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. From discussions I've seen, it seems as though it's common practice to put behaviour into enums. Not something I would have assumed, coming from a C background, however.

Comment: @scottb Vivin is using the interface for the values not for the keys. So EnumMap is the way to go.

Comment: the problem with behavior code in enums is that enums are static and one need a good understanding of when what is initialized within enums. and if there is an error within enum behavior code it is hard to track and also not test-able

Comment: @danwag Java's enum are a language level support for the Typesafe Enum Pattern. You can implement this OO pattern also with other languages, but usually it requires more code if there is no language level support.

Comment: @danwag, yes it is allowed, but you have to be pragmatic about it. I like to put very little behavior into enums, and almost never have enums dealing with business-logic. You don't want to end up with a "heavy" enum that has a ton of behavior; you're better off with dedicated classes for that. It's also surprising from an API perspective, since people don't normally associate complex behavior with enums.

Comment: @Andreas: it does not appear that you have a good working understanding of Java rich enum types.  Your assertion that constant-specific behaviors are untestable is false.  For further information about Java enum types, please see Effective Java, 2nd Ed.

Comment: @VivinPaliath: Enums are classes, so the notion that a typical class is better than a "heavy enum" is arguable.  In particular, the use of Java rich enum types has the capability to make code less fragile, easier to maintain, and more secure than code that relies on, say, singletons or integer enum types.  The key to having good enums is in designing a good enum.  Code with a badly designed enum will still be badly designed if the enum is replaced by a class.

Comment: @scottb No, they are not; they have completely different semantics. The issue is not bad design. The issue is the kind of semantics you want to convey. The **most common** semantic conveyed through enums is that you are defining a **static**, **predefined** set of values. Yes, you can associate behavior, but this usually comes in the form of additional information associated with an enum ([like the `Planet` example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)) [contd]

Comment: @scottb But if you are doing things like talking to a database, or making HTTP calls from within an enum, then you are most definitely doing too much. That sort of responsibility doesn't lie with the enum, and there are better, **more obvious** and **less surprising** ways to design your code. A good rule of thumb for an API is the principle of least surprise. If I was using an API, it would not be obvious to me that I could invoke complex behavior from an enum, because that's usually in a service. [contd]

Comment: @scottb I can't think of any API/framework I have used that implemented very complex logic in an enum. The point is that the design has to be pragmatic. I'm not advocating a dogmatic approach of "no logic at all", but at some point there is too much complex logic in an enum, not to mention we already can use classes to do the same thing. Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should. Java lets you put multiple classes in a single file, but there's a reason we don't do it. We can also put everything in a "God" class, but we don't do that either.

Comment: @VivinPaliath, if you have "very complex" logic, that probably shouldn't go into _any_ single class (enum or "normal"), but instead should be refactored into separate units of code. One example of a rich enum in a very popular framework is Guava´s [`CaseFormat`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.java). As can be seen from the source, it's ~200 LOC and very feature rich; yet the class is concise and the functionality is very clear for the reader because of the _declarative_ style of coding that using an enum allows.

Comment: In my opinion, when the business domain contains enumerable elements and the problem at hand can be formulated as a "compile-time constant" (as in Guava´s `CaseFormat`), enums are a much cleaner way to code your domain logic than plain old "normal" classes. Coding business logic into a "service layer" can also be seen as an anti-pattern, because it easily leads to an [anemic domain model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).

Comment: @MickMnemonic I meant "very complex" in a relative sense. I agree with you that overly-complex logic should be split into separate units. I think what `CaseFormat` does is fine because the behavior that it defines is solely within the context of each of those values and conforms to the semantics of those values. But if your enum needs to know about other dependencies, then the behavior is no-longer in the context of the enum values themselves. I think we are talking about the same thing, and you hit upon it exactly when you mentioned that the implementation is **concise**.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish a declarative style of coding and using enums is definitely one way of doing that. While using services *can* lead to an anemic domain-model, having services doesn't necessarily imply that it *will*. As with any design-pattern, there are exceptions and tradeoffs; you use the best tool for the job and try to be pragmatic about your design decisions.